# Additional IP address to loopback via /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking

I want to add `169.254.255.254` to loopback interface so I can use `hostlocal.io` to unambiguously refer to the host from docker containers. I don't want to run a [docker container](https://github.com/gliderlabs/hostlocal) for it, so I thought of adding it to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

So I've tried

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto lo.1
iface lo.1 inet static
  address 169.254.255.254/24
```

but that complained that lo.1 does not exist. Then I tried just

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet static
  address 169.254.255.254/24
```

but it did not seem to have any effect. So I hacked it as

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
        post-up ip addr add 169.254.255.254/24 dev lo:0
        pre-down ip addr del 169.254.255.254/24 dev lo:0
```

which works, but feels hacky. What is the proper way to add the other address?

Note: I do have network manager, but as far as I can tell, loopback is not under its control and still defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so it seems better approach to stick to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were very close! To accomplish the lo addressing they way you are looking you might have to use a `:[num]` notation. You might be able to write out your address with mask in the interfaces file, but I used the traditional notation with address, netmask and network.

**`/etc/network/interfaces`**:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo lo:0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp

iface lo:0 inet static
  address 169.254.255.254
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 169.254.255.0
```

The resulting IP address on lo becomes:

```
user@server:~$ ip addr show dev lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.255.254/24 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global lo:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
user@server:~$
```

I thought that the 169.254.0.0/16 range was used for link local - but you can modify the above as needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The range 169.254.0.0/16 is indeed link-local. With some eye-squinting it is kinda what is happening here—it is meant to be local to the internal virtual neworks. But mainly there is a public DNS record for it, `hostlocal.io` that I've seen used in some Microsoft Dockerfile templates. Otherwise of course the host has another IP in those networks anyway, so one of them can be used instead (`172.17.0.1` of `docker0`).

Comment: I think in this case all that matters is the IP is assigned - it isn't like you are communicating with devices in the full range of 169.254.0.0-169.254.255.255. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work now. Thanks.